# Fetching Python Google Users API query in webapp2 returns None

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

I'm trying to use a React-based frontend to connect to some endpoints hosted by webapp2 using Python and Google App Engine. For the initial authentication page, I'm using the Google Users API. For some reason I can write out the user's info on my local development server but cannot retrieve it using Javascript's Fetch API, as it returns None when I attempt to.

I've tried writing out the users as strings but no matter what it still returns none.

Here is the Python code:

```py
def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        logout_url = users.create_logout_url('/')
        login_url = users.create_login_url('/')
        if user:
            greeting = ('Welcome, %s! (<a href="%s">sign out</a>)' %
                (user.email(), logout_url))
        else:
            greeting = ('<a href="%s">Sign in or register</a>.' % login_url)

        if users.get_current_user():
            us = users.get_current_user().email()
            us = User.query(User.email == us).fetch()

            if us:
                pass
            else:
                us = User(
                    email= users.get_current_user().email(),
                    posts=[]
                )
                us.put()

        vars = {
            'data': user,
            'greeting': greeting
        }
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
        self.response.write(vars)
```

When I access http://localhost:8080 for example, I'll get the response `{'data': users.User(email='i@example.com',_user_id='14123123123'), 'greeting': 'Welcome, i@example.com! (sign out)'}`.

When I try to fetch it however,

```
const fatch = () => fetch('http://localhost:8080')
  .then(data => console.log(data.text()))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

I'll get a response that has none of the user info:

```
{'data': None, 'greeting': '<a href="/_ah/login?co…3A//localhost%3A8080/">Sign in or register</a>.'}
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly. Thanks!

Comment: Inside your `def get(self):` print the request headers. Your `fetch` function probably isn't sending the cookies that the browser request was sending

Comment: Yup - you'll probably get the same result in the browser in an incognito window until you actually log in - from the `else` branch of `if user:`.

Comment: This is what I get: `Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type`